Date picker mount and year jetpack compose
How can I make it so that when opening the calendar, the user can select only the month and year in jetpack compose. I did not find such a way in the documentation.
I tried to change the date picker somehow, but it didn't work, I think I need to create my own, but I don't really want to do that.

Here's a basic idea on how you can implement this in Jetpack Compose
Month Selection : Use a dropdown or a list of months for selection.
Year Selection : Use Scroll-able column or a slider to let users pick a year
  @Composable
fun MonthYearPicker(
    selectedMonth: String,
    selectedYear: Int,
    onMonthSelected: (String) -> Unit,
    onYearSelected: (Int) -> Unit,
    currentYear: Int = 2024,
    yearRange: IntRange = (1900..currentYear)
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val months = listOf(
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    )

    Column {`enter code here`
        // Month Picker
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded }
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = selectedMonth,
                onValueChange = {},
                readOnly = true,
                label = { Text("Select Month") },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown, null)
                }
            )
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                months.forEach { month ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        onMonthSelected(month)
                        expanded = false
                    }) {
                        Text(text = month)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Year Picker
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp) // Set an appropriate height
        ) {
            items(yearRange.toList()) { year ->
                Text(
                    text = year.toString(),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .clickable { onYearSelected(year) }
                )
            }
        }
    }}


I think user doesn't want to create custom date picker!
